# I'm interested in trying out Ubuntu. I installed 12.04 i386 on usb stick, but can't get it to boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb, windows-7

I am currently running Windows 7. I'm not quite sure how to get this to boot into Ubuntu. I have the usb stick in drive, and I restart the computer, but nothing changes. I tried f12 before the windows startup prompt, still nothing. I downloaded 12.04 i386 using the steps in "Pen Drive USB Linux's installer" on this site. I can go into "devices" and browse files on the usb, but I can't get the option to "try Ubuntu". What am I missing?  Also, in the usb download, there was 12.04 i386 and 12.04 amd. What's the difference? What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: To make your question clearer, you will need to edit your question to include the following:  1. How did you install Ubuntu to the USB(what program did you use) 2. Did you check the integrity of the USB install with [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM), Windows instr. are halfway down.

Comment: To answer your second question.  i386 downloads are 32bit.  AMD are 64bit.  Most Windows 7 computer are 64bit capable even if the 32bit OS is installed.  64bit will give better performance, but depending on your usage it may not be noticeable.  The more important thing is that 32bit OSs' CANNOT run 64bit programs.  64bit OSs' can run 32 bit programs if the 32bit libraries are installed.(at least in Linux, not sure about Windows) A 64bit CPU's can run a 32bit OS, but a 32bit CPU cannot run a 64bit OS. If you have any other question, search for Mutli-arch on this site, I'm out of room here.

Comment: Instead asking several questions in "one question", ask 1 question per post so people are more willing to answer you.

Comment: need more info, please give a feedback and rating, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what's going on here. You are rebooting the machine, but your machine is booting back to the hard drive (with Windows 7 on it), and NOT to the USB stick.

Computers look at a specific device to boot from, and yours is set to boot from the hard drive. You simply need to change this to boot into the USB stick (and into the live Ubuntu environment).

To accomplish this, you should do one of two things:

1. Find out which key (delete, escape, F12, etc) loads your computer's BOOT MENU. You should tap this key repeatedly as soon as the machine boots. When the boot menu appears select the USB device.
2. You need to go into your machine's BIOS and change the BOOT ORDER so that the machine tries to boot to a USB device before the hard drive. Getting to the BIOS and changing the boot order will vary between each different machine, Google has pretty good search functionality, so you could try that.